# Rendering Rich Text from CMS in Gatsby v4

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, gatsby, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to render rich text in my Gatsby v4 about page for my site, but I'm having trouble finding any info on how to render the data. I've read about adding blocks, but I'm lost on what I should be including or how to go about this. I really just need to render links, headers, and body text in the rich text. Could someone walk me through this?

Here's my component code snippet. The data is all coming through the query correctly in the page so far. I just want the text to go where it says "TEXT GOES HERE"

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import {renderRichText} from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
import {BLOCKS, MARKS} from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import * as aboutStyles from "../styles/about.module.scss"

const query = graphql`
{
  contentfulAbout {
    about
    bioImage {
      title
      url
      gatsbyImageData(
        layout: FULL_WIDTH
        placeholder: BLURRED
        resizingBehavior: SCALE
        width: 1000
      )
    }
    aboutText {
      raw
    }
  }
}
`

const AboutSection = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query);
  const contentfulAbout = data.contentfulAbout
  return (
    <div className={aboutStyles.parent}>
      <section className={aboutStyles.container}>
          <div className={aboutStyles.image}>
            <GatsbyImage className={aboutStyles.bioImage} image={contentfulAbout.bioImage.gatsbyImageData} alt={contentfulAbout.bioImage.title} />
          </div>
          <div className={aboutStyles.text}>
            <h2>{contentfulAbout.about}</h2>
            <p>TEXT GOES HERE</p>
          </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use the exposed `BLOCKS` and `MARKS` to fully customize the fetched data from Contentful like:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    },
  },
}
​
renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

Source: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/

In that way, you can render a `span` with "bold" `className` when a `MARKS.BOLD` is fetched, using your own customized output.

In the snippet above, there's missing the implementation into a "standard" component, but the idea relies on the same fact. Using `renderRichText` what accepts two arguments:

- The first one: your rich text node (`aboutText` in your case)
- The second argument: the `options` with your custom output

Applied to your code, it should look like:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
import * as aboutStyles from "../styles/about.module.scss"

const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <strong>{text}</strong>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <p>{children}</p>,
  },
}


const query = graphql`
{
  contentfulAbout {
    about
    bioImage {
      title
      url
      gatsbyImageData(
        layout: FULL_WIDTH
        placeholder: BLURRED
        resizingBehavior: SCALE
        width: 1000
      )
    }
    aboutText {
      raw
    }
  }
}
`

const AboutSection = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query);
  const contentfulAbout = data.contentfulAbout
  return (
    <div className={aboutStyles.parent}>
      <section className={aboutStyles.container}>
          <div className={aboutStyles.image}>
            <GatsbyImage className={aboutStyles.bioImage} image={contentfulAbout.bioImage.gatsbyImageData} alt={contentfulAbout.bioImage.title} />
          </div>
          <div className={aboutStyles.text}>
            <h2>{contentfulAbout.about}</h2>
            <p>{renderRichText(contentfulAbout.aboutText, options)}</p>
          </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Of course, it may need some tweaking. Note that I've simplified the output so customize it as you wish/need.

Other resources:

- https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/rich-text/

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately, when I added this code I'm now receiving this error: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Is there something else I need to add to the code?

Comment: Sorry, according to the docs (https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/) you don't need to use `raw`, just `aboutText` directly

Comment: If the issue has been solved, please consider accepting the answer to close the issue